# Is there a way to order JUnit testcases in TeamCity?

Tags: configuration, junit, teamcity

Let's say I have three JUnit test cases, namely `TC1, TC2` and `TC3`. Is there a way to configure **TeamCity** or **pom** somehow, so that when I `remote run`, the order will be TC1 -> TC2 -> TC3 always?

Right now, because of unordering in test cases, all these tests start with the same  functionality (for example: creating a user), which takes a pretty big amount of time. I would like to do that functionality in the first test case only (TC1 in this case). I am open for any other approaches also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, because of it is unordered, these three test cases include common functionalities, and it increases the running time of testcases, I will update my question

Comment: Unit tests should be able to run in any order. It sounds more like your tests need work rather than forcing an order on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maven-failsafe-plugin` has an optional parameter, `runOrder` which is exactly what I wanted. You can set it to `alphabetical` and afterwards, you modify the name of your testcases, you are done.